# How do i return a structure defined and populated in C/C++ to java via JNI in android?

Tags: java, android, c

Below mentioned is the function defined in C which i will be calling from java like this **`Getdevicedetails(string)`**  :

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_example_myapplicationforc_MainActivity_getdevicedetails(JNIEnv* env, jobject value,jstring stringfromjava)
```

Structure created on C side:

```
struct deviceinfo
    {
        char manufacturer[PROP_VALUE_MAX + 1];
        char model[PROP_VALUE_MAX + 1];
        char brand[PROP_VALUE_MAX + 1];
        char SDK[PROP_VALUE_MAX + 1];
        char buildrelease[PROP_VALUE_MAX + 1];
        //char serialno[PROP_VALUE_MAX + 1];
        char imeino[PROP_VALUE_MAX + 1];
    };

struct deviceinfo *devicedetail = (struct deviceinfo *) malloc(sizeof(deviceinfo));
```

After populating this structure, while returning, i'm converting this to a java object and returning it like this

```
return env->NewGlobalRef(jobject (devicedetail));
```

On javaside, im receiving the object like this:

```
Object jobjt = getdevicedetails(paramstring);
```

But it crashes on launching the app. Any clue where im going wrong ? when i pass each structure member as string from C to java , it works and displays in java/android app. But while returning the reference of the object , it crashes. Looking for help.

Comment: I guess you cannot convert your C structure to Java object just like that. This explanation about passing data through JNI might be helpful: https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2013/08/android-ndk-passing-complex-data-to-jni.html

Comment: Thanks Wierzmar... the link you provided has details with good examples.. this will help...